# Mac OS: bash: No CVSROOT specified

Tags: bash, macos, cvs, vcs-checkout

Mac OS 10.7.4

I need to checkout ~70 cvs projects so I have script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cvs checkout proj1
cvs checkout proj2
cvs checkout proj3

....

cvs ckeckout proj75
```

But when I execute it I have an error message:

```
cvs checkout: No CVSROOT specified! Please use the '-d' option
cvs [checkout aborted]: or set the CVSROOT environment variable.
```

When I write manualy `cvs checkout proj1` in works.

```
ECHO $CVSROOT
:pserver:mylogin@server:port/repository
```

Would appreciate any hints to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the "`$CVSROOT`" explicitly in your shell script and see if that makes a difference.

It may be that you're launching another shell (i.e. "`bash`") and the environment variables from your current shell, whatever it is, aren't being copied into your bash environment.

Comment: Or you have set `CVSROOT` but not `export`ed it, which means child processes will not inherit it.